# What are best number randomizers which can be input into another line?

Tags: command-line

I want to make random lines like, so how to make random number generators example for 3 numbers like 000-999?
Which cane incorporated/included/combined into another command like

```
curl 123999blabla.html
curl 123111blabla.html
curl 123000blabla.html
```

Answer (score 1):

The command is:

```
curl `printf "%.3d" $(( $RANDOM % 1000 ))``printf "%.3d" $(( $RANDOM % 1000 ))`blabla.html
```

Explanation:

- `$(( $RANDOM % 1000 ))` creates an (almost) random number in the range 0-999
- `printf "%.3d" 12` formats the number (in this case 12 but in the command above the output of the random division) with a leading zero(es)
- the backtick around the printf command insert the output of the inner command into the outer
- you get 2 of the above because your command examples seem to have series of 2*3 random numbers
- blabla.html at the end appends the static text

Your curl example isn't perfect because you need to supply a URL, not a file name to curl. May I suggest using `echo` until you are happy with the output.

Comment: will it make 000 also and not just 0?

Comment: Yes, it will. You can test it in the bash prompt: `printf "%.3d\n" 0`